# How do I do masked fill in mlx?

Tags: python, machine-learning, pytorch, tensor

I want to implement masked_fill in mlx but it doesn't play nice with float('-inf')

https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.Tensor.masked_fill.html

I'm trying to use mlx.core.where for this

```
masked_tensor = mlx.core.where(mask, mlx.core.array(float('-inf')), mlx.core.array(0))
```

but for the mask

```
array([[False, False, True, True],                                                                                                                                                      
       [False, False, True, True],                                                                                                                                                     
       [False, False, True, True],                                                                                                                                                    
       [False, False, True, True]], dtype=bool)
```

this returns

```
array([[nan, nan, -inf, -inf],                                                                                                                                              
       [nan, nan, -inf, -inf],                                                                                                                                                
       [nan, nan, -inf, -inf],                                                                                            
       [nan, nan, -inf, -inf]], dtype=float32)
```

which is not what I want. Ideally it would return

```
array([[0, 0, -inf, -inf],                                                                                                                                              
       [0, 0, -inf, -inf],                                                                                                                                                
       [0, 0, -inf, -inf],                                                                                            
       [0, 0, -inf, -inf]], dtype=float32)
```

help

Answer (score 1):

This should work with the latest mlx: `pip install -U mlx`

```bash
>>> import mlx.core as mx
>>> mask = mx.array([True, False])
>>> mx.where(mask, mx.array(float("-inf")), mx.array(0.0))
array([-inf, 0], dtype=float32)
```